# Deserialize Postgres ARRAY [@tags] to List<string> with Dapper?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dapper

I'm using Dapper with Npsql (Postgres). I'm saving a serialized list of strings to one column called `tags`:

```cs
values.Tags = new List<string>() { "first", "second" };

await Connection.ExecuteAsync(
    @"INSERT INTO account (text, tags) VALUES (@text, ARRAY [@tags]);",
    new
    {
        text = values.Text,
        tags = values.Tags
    }
);
```

which is resulting in `{{first,second}}` in the database.

My question is how to read it back to the model? Do I need some special SQL, or can I use `SELECT id, text, tags FROM account;`?

How can I dapper tell to deserialize it back to `List<string>`?

Thanks

Comment: Question (and for context, I wrote Dapper, and don't use Postgresql): if you use select id, text, tags (as per the question), what is reader.GetValue(0).GetType()  on a reader for that query? It influences how to do this

Comment: reader.GetValue(2).GetType() (not index zero, but index 2, index 0 is an 'id' column which you are probably not interested in) returns: `{Name = "String[,]" FullName = "System.String[,]"}`. `reader.GetValue(2)` value is `{string[1, 2]}` of type `object {string[,]}`.

Comment: interesting - a 2D string array; I would not have guessed that, but I can also confirm: Dapper has no specific handling built in for that type (or any other 2D array as output). We could certainly *add* support if it is a common scenario, but it isn't a need I've encountered (probably because I don't use postgresql)

Comment: Is there a way I can hookup into the parsing and do it for a specific model/property?

Comment: there is a type-handler API in Dapper, but: I honestly haven't tried it in this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c# dapper code would look like the following (where notes & comments are a list of strings):

```
string query = "INSERT INTO calendar.testtable VALUES (@A, @B, @C)";
await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, new { A = model.Key, B = model.Notes, C = model.Comments });
```

To let .NET, Dapper, and Postgres know how to handle the list of strings, create the following class.

```
public class StringListTypeHandler<T> : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<List<string>>
{
    public override List<string> Parse(object value)
    {
        return ((string[])value).ToList();
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, List<string> value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Finally, add the following to your ConfigureServices() method within your Startup class

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new StringListTypeHandler<List<string>>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working TypeHandler class:

```cs
public class StringListTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<IList<string>>
{
    public override IList<string> Parse(object value)
    {
        var values = (string[,])value;

        IList<string> list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            list.Add(values[0, i]);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, IList<string> value)
    {
        parameter.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Register it as: `Dapper.SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new StringListTypeHandler());`